# Calculating probability in iterative double pigeonhole type problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Assume I have $2n$ unique members of a set. Now assume that each element of that set is assigned an integer $\in (0,n]$, such that each integer is used twice. So for example if you have a set of 4 elements which we label $\{A,B,C,D\}$, then two elements will be labeled with 1 and two will be labeled 2, e.g. you might get the labeled set: $\{(A,1),(B,1),(C,2),(D,2)\}.$

Now assume the labels of the $2n$ elements are completely randomized. My question is, **what is the probability $p_n$ that no pair of elements that shared a label, both got that same label again (for arbitrary values of $n$)?** To continue the example before (for $n=2$), the 6 distinct ways the 4 labels can be arranged are:
$$\{(A,1),(B,1),(C,2),(D,2)\}\\
\{(A,1),(B,2),(C,1),(D,2)\}\\
\{(A,1),(B,2),(C,2),(D,1)\}\\
\{(A,2),(B,1),(C,1),(D,2)\}\\
\{(A,2),(B,1),(C,2),(D,1)\}\\
\{(A,2),(B,2),(C,1),(D,1)\}.$$
Because there is only one case where either $A$ and $B$ where both reassigned 1 and/or $C$ and $D$ where reassigned 2, the probability for $n=2$ is $p_2=5/6$.

Ideally I would like a closed form solution for $p_n$, but I'd also settle for a recursive formula (which could e.g. be used to numerically compute $p_n$ by say an iterated python script)

Comment: A somewhat related question, with triples instead of pairs, is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216025/what-is-the-probability-of-at-least-one-group-having-the-same-members-when-36-pe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid having any of the $n$ events which consist of each of the $n$ pairs repeating, we can get the probability of this with inclusion exclusion.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of labels on $2n$ elements, where $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 6$ etcetera.

The probability that a given subset of $k$ pairs repeats is $\frac{f(n-k)}{f(n)}$, because there are $f(n-k)$ ways to label the remaining $2(n-k)$ elements.

Hence via inclusion-exclusion the probability that no event happens is:

$1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{f(n-k)}{f(n)}$.

Where $f(n)$ is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n }$

Comment: I assume that should be $(-1)^k$ rather than $(-1)^n$ in the formula for the probability, correct?

Comment: yes sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to understand. Is this the probability that no two elements that were paired initially get the exact same pair, or is it the probability that no two elements are paired twice (which could be via assignment of any of the n labels)?

E.g. If ABCDEF... where assigned 771243..., then I'm only interested in cases where  AB aren't both assigned 7 again (and likewise for each of the n pairs)

Comment: Oh ok, it's the former. I'll fix this tomorrow morning then, but the solution is similar.

Comment: Oh nevermind I think the fix is easier than I thought, should be good now.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!